# Is it possible to carry out a one-tailed chi square test in Stata?

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, stata

I am trying to understand whether there is a difference in proportions for a dataset in two time periods using a 2x2 contingency table. The null hypothesis is that there is an expected increase between the two periods (Right sided one tailed test). How can this be implemented? here is a sample table. Null hypothesis is that there is no change.

```
+----------+---------+---------+
|          | Periodx | Periody |
+----------+---------+---------+
| Positive |     759 |    4000 |
| Negative |    7992 |    2130 |
+----------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Let's focus on the statistics here and forget about Stata implementation, which is off-topic here. How are expected frequencies defined for your problem? Please give a small but realistic example with similar structure to your real problem.

Comment: { Periodx          Periody
Positive     759            4000
Negative    7992            2130 }

Comment: ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Periodx          Periody
Positive     759            4000
Negative    7992            2130

Comment: How are expected frequencies defined?